# Primefaces FileUpload Extensions Filter

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, file-upload

I need to **view** only some list of extensions in the dialog not even choosing them as a possible variant of file. Using p:FileUpload.

Answer (score 0):

Per the Primefaces Development Guide 2.2,

> allowTypes - Semi colon separated list of file extensions to accept.

The following is an attribute of the fileUpload component tag.

Comment: no, it seems you can choose files of another extensions but the message will be shown that the extension is invalid. and i need even not to view files of other extensions except for some definite list of them.

Comment: i mean that this doesn't help <p:fileUpload  id="docUpload" allowTypes="jpg,png,jpeg" value="#{uploadDocBean.docContent}" mode="simple">

Comment: What version of Primefaces are you using?  There is no `mode` attribute as of Primefaces 2.2.1.