# primefaces fileupload invalid file type doc, docx

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces, facelets

I want to upload doc or docx file using primefaces fileUpload,although I specify the type of file it display 
**Invalid file type**

[image]

```xml
<p:fileUpload cancelLabel="#{contenu.annuler}"
    fileUploadListener="#{utilAdminBean.fileUpload}"
    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(doc|docx)$/"
    multiple="false" mode="advanced" sizeLimit="52428800"
    showButtons="false" />
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6343213/1016716) says that allowTypes is a "Semi colon separated list of file extensions to accept". But it seems to depend on which version of Primefaces you use.

Comment: It works fine for me using PRIMEFACES 3.5.

Comment: What is the primefaces version you are using? And also specify JSF Impl.

Comment: you could specify the `allowTypes`like this: `allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(doc?x)$/"` but this is not relevant for this to work. but with 3.5 and 4.0 it works for me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the solution,I forgot to add to the fileupload component inside `<h:form nctype="multipart/form-data">`

functional code is as follows:

```xml
<h:form id="formcontract" enctype="multipart/form-data" dir="rtl">
    <p:fileUpload cancelLabel="#{contenu.annuler}"
        fileUploadListener="#{utilAdminBean.fileUpload}"
        allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(doc|docx|xls|xlsx|pdf)$/"
        multiple="false" mode="advanced" sizeLimit="52428800"
        showButtons="false" />
</h:form>
```