# How to allow users to upload any type of files except image file types in PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In this fileUpload, I need to make it to allow any type of files except image file types. However, it seems like my regular expression in allowTypes is not work. Do you guys have any idea how to do this?

This is my code:

```
<p:fileUpload id="anyfiles" fileUploadListener="#{newsAdminBean.handleFilesUpload}" mode="advanced" auto="true" dragDropSupport="false" multiple="true" sizeLimit="5242880" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(\*|^png|^jpe?g|^gif)$/" uploadLabel="อัพโหลด" cancelLabel="ยกเลิก" label="เลือก" process="@this,upTablists" update="upTablists" invalidSizeMessage="ขนาดไฟล์เกิน 5 MB"/>
```

Comment: How try with regex `/(.+\.)(?!(png|jpe?g|gif))/g`, see link [here](http://regex101.com/r/dY7iM2/1)

Comment: see the answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720985/primefaces-fileupload-invalid-file-type-doc-docx